# How to get the attachment from storage mailed in Mailgun with Elixir

Tags: elixir, mailgun

I have extracted the attachment from stored email in Mailgun.

`https://sw.api.mailgun.net/v3/domains/xxxx.com/messages/AgEFb9QUzk8HBO7pSwVMB6qZaW0hSig8ZA==`

Now I need a way to download this on a file on my server.

```
url = "https://api:key-81c9c48ae617bc0d2@sw.api.mailgun.net/v3/domains/xxxx.com/messages/AgEFb9QUzk8HBO7pSwVMB6qZaW0hSig8ZA=="

headers = ["Accept": "message/rfc2822"]

{:ok, response} =  HTTPoison.get(url, headers)
```

Result:

```
%HTTPoison.Response{
  body: "{\"body-mime\": \"X-Mailgun-Incoming: Yes\\r\\nX-Envelope-From:....}

{:ok, decoded} = response.body |> Poison.decode

iex(14)> Map.keys(decoded)

["Content-Type", "Date", "Dkim-Signature", "From", "Message-Id", "Mime-Version",
 "Received", "Subject", "To", "X-Envelope-From", "X-Gm-Message-State",
 "X-Google-Dkim-Signature", "X-Google-Smtp-Source", "X-Mailgun-Incoming",
 "X-Received", "body-mime", "from", "recipients", "sender", "subject"]
```

From the above only `"body-mime"` makes sense so:

when I `decoded["body-mime"]` out there is only a massive text with the entire email in there.

So I think I am going wrong somewhere.

There is no documentation for this or I can't find it!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your url the url of the attachment?

If so, you can use `File.write` to actually save a file to your server.

So, if the attachment is an image, for example.

```
%HTTPoison.Response{body: body} = HTTPoison.get!(url)

File.write!("/tmp/image.png", body)
```

If your url is actually just the email itself, there should be an `attachments` in the response that gives the URL of the attachments, which you can still get as described above.

Answer (score 1):

The [Mailgun API documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html) says about `body-mime`:

> full MIME envelope. You will need a MIME parsing library to process this data.

One such library is https://github.com/DockYard/elixir-mail. You should be able to get the attachments like this:

```
decoded["body-mime"] |> Mail.Parsers.RFC2822.parse() |> Mail.get_attachments()
```